# how to put a button inside div where data is filled dynamically through $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be very simple but i am struggling here.

I have a parent div which have multiple child div. These child div are generated according to $.each() function. Number of times function run, num of div get generated.Now, i want to write a server side function on button click but i am unable to list that button in these child div.

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    // this is the button which i cant see in my div2 div
    <button type="input">follow</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetUsers", null, function(data) {
          $(".div1").html("");
          $.each(data, function(i, item) {

            var html = "<div class='div2'>";
            html += "Name: " + item.UserName + "<br />";
            html += item.ArticleCount;
            html += "<img src='" + item.UserImage + "'height='20px' width='20px'/>"
            html += "</div>";
            $(".div1").append(html);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any type of guidance appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a button per child div, or a single button on the parent div?

Comment: There will be only one DIV as per your code.

Comment: A button per child div @JamesHay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to add a button per child div you can do it in this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var parent = $(".div1");

    $.getJSON("/Home/GetUsers", null, function(data) {

      parent.html("");

      $.each(data, function(i, item) {

        var html = "<div class='div2'>";
        html += "Name: " + item.UserName + "<br />";
        html += item.ArticleCount;
        html += "<img src='" + item.UserImage + "'height='20px' width='20px'/>";
        html += "<button type='button' class='newButton'>Click Me!</button>";
        html += "</div>";

        parent.append(html);
      });

    });

    // In order to ensure that the button click is handled no matter when it was 
    // added, we can delegate the handler to the parent.

    parent.on('click', '.newButton', function(e) {
       var button = $(this);

       // Handle the individual button click server side call here.
    });
  });
```

Comment: thnk u for answering with button click event handling that would have troubled me more will try it asap @James Hay